# Disconnect and Connect Azure VM from LogAnalytics worspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to search is there a way to execute a powershell command that can disconnect and connect from log analytics workspace a list of azure vm's all at the same time not just one, is this possible.

This is the powershell command to disconnect the vm from the workspace:

```
Remove-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName RESOURCEGROUPNAME -VMName VMNAME -Name ‘OmsAgentForLinux’
```

and this one is for connecting the vm:

```
$WorkspaceID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$WorkspaceKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName RESOURCEGROUPNAME -VMName VMNAME -Name ‘OmsAgentForLinux’ -Publisher ‘Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring’ -ExtensionType ‘OmsAgentForLinux’ -TypeHandlerVersion ‘1.0’ -Location 'LOCATION' -SettingString "{‘workspaceId’: ‘$WorkspaceID’}" -ProtectedSettingString "{‘workspaceKey’: ‘$WorkspaceKey’}"
```

Comment: Could you please let us know what is the error ,are you getting by running the above command. Or we can use the az module instead for example refer this [**MS DOC**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/remove-azvmextension?view=azps-7.5.0)

Comment: Hi,
thanks for you're time! is not an error perse is that I want to know if I can run the command to various vm's at the same time is that possible?

Comment: It might be, But are you getting any error while running the given command in your environment?